# Combining an individual and aggregate level data sets

Tags: r

I've got two different data frames, lets call them "Months" and "People".

Months looks like this:

```
Month   Site   X
1       1      4
2       1      3
3       1      5
1       2      10
2       2      7
3       2      5
```

and People looks like this:

```
ID   Month   Site
1    1       1
2    1       2
3    1       1
4    2       2
5    2       2
6    2       2
7    3       1
8    3       2
```

I'd like to combine them so essentially each time an entry in "People" has a particular Month and Site combination, it's added to the appropriate aggregated data frame, so I'd get something like the following:

```
Month   Site   X   People
1       1      4   2
2       1      3   0
3       1      5   1
1       2      10  1
2       2      7   3
3       2      5   1
```

But I haven't the foggiest idea of how to go about doing that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using base packages

```
> aggregate( ID ~ Month + Site, data=People, FUN = length )
  Month Site ID
1     1    1  2
2     3    1  1
3     1    2  1
4     2    2  3
5     3    2  1
> res <- merge(Months, aggdata, all.x = TRUE)

> res
  Month Site  X ID
1     1    1  4  2
2     1    2 10  1
3     2    1  3 NA
4     2    2  7  3
5     3    1  5  1
6     3    2  5  1
> res[is.na(res)] <- 0
> res
  Month Site  X ID
1     1    1  4  2
2     1    2 10  1
3     2    1  3  0
4     2    2  7  3
5     3    1  5  1
6     3    2  5  1
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `data.frame`s are `months` and `people`, here's a `data.table` solution:

```
require(data.table)
m.dt <- data.table(months, key=c("Month", "Site"))
p.dt <- data.table(people, key=c("Month", "Site"))
# one-liner
dt.f <- p.dt[m.dt, list(X=X[1], People=sum(!is.na(ID)))]

> dt.f

#    Month Site  X People
# 1:     1    1  4      2
# 2:     1    2 10      1
# 3:     2    1  3      0
# 4:     2    2  7      3
# 5:     3    1  5      1
# 6:     3    2  5      1
```